# C# How to write this ternary operation

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, conditional-operator

```
GetDati(id).Tables[0].Rows.count > 0 ? GetDati(id).Tables[0].Rows[0]: null;
```

How should I write this line? I want to call only one time the `GetDati()`.

Comment: Store its result in X then use X in the ternary?

Comment: Why not just use a variable to store the part of the return value that you are using in a statement just prior to this?

Comment: If you make an SQL statement that returns only exactly one value (or nothing), use `ExecuteScalar` on the Command objekt to return this value directly instead of getting a Dataset and working with that.

Comment: Also you can try ?? operator, since 2.0 like this
GetDati(id).Tables[0].Rows[0] ?? null;

checkout https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator

Answer (score 4):

> i want to call only 1 time the fnuction GetDati

Then call it only once and store the result in a variable.  For example:

```
var dati = GetDati(id);
var result = dati.Tables[0].Rows.count > 0 ? dati.Tables[0].Rows[0]: null
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also take advantage of pattern matching in C# 8:

```
var result = GetDati(id).Tables[0].Rows is var rows && rows.Count > 0 ? rows[0] : null;
```

The `is` introduces a test against a [pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching). A `var` pattern will always succeed, and assigns the result to the `rows` variable.

---

That said, I find the version used by @David to be clearer, but I know some people prefer using a `var` pattern.

Answer (score 2):

```
var rows = GetDati(id).Tables[0].Rows;
var result = rows.count > 0 ? rows[0]: null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you but if I need to call this on constructor like this:

```
Public myclass(DataRoe dr):this(){
   Do something
}

Public myclass(id):this(getdati(id).tables[0].rows[0]){}
```

Comment: You can use a static helper method